# Django-taggit query objects if the tag field contains 2 or more elements?

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I'm wondering how to query multiple tags through taggit. I'm currently using django-taggit. I'm using pizza as a placeholder name. How can I filter in a way that only returns objects that contain 2 or more tags?  For example, if I wanted to query different types of pizzas:

```
>>> Pizza.objects.create(name='Pizza 1', tags=[pepperoni])
>>> Pizza.objects.create(name='Pizza 2', tags=[pepperoni, chicken, onions])
>>> Pizza.objects.create(name='Pizza 3', tags=[pepperoni, sausage, cheese, onions])

>>> Pizza.objects.filter(tags__contains=['pepperoni', 'onions'])
    <QuerySet [<Pizza: Pizza 2>, <Pizza: Pizza 3> ]>
```

Here is the current implementation of django-taggit. It queries the tags separately, but often times my objects will share 1 tag, but not 2 tags. I would like to query if 2 or more tags are present.

**models.py**

```
class UUIDTaggedItem(GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tag")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tags")

class Pizza(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True, through=UUIDTaggedItem)
```

**filters.py**

```
class TagsFilter(CharFilter):

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value:
            tags = [tag.strip() for tag in value.split(',')]
            qs = qs.filter(tags__name__in=tags).distinct()

        return qs

class PizzaFilter(filterset.FilterSet):

    tags = TagsFilter(field_name="tags", lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Pizza
```

I'm also using postgres as my db, I've considered using ArrayField, but I've read a stack overflow questions that don't suggest using ArrayField for tags.

Comment: Have you tried `Pizza.objects.filter(tags__name='pepperoni').filter(tags__name='onions')`?

Comment: I read a Django article that chaining filters is not recommended for performance. http://www.effectivedjango.com/orm.html. I think I would avoid using chained filters because of that.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, @Jazure? I'm trying to do the same thing -- avoid chaining filters or, at the very least, use composed Q objects and it's not working.